# Disable Debugging on ASP.NET site

Tags: c#, asp.net, debugging, iis

Our security team wants me to disable debugging on an ASP.NET site that I have developed.  They object to the server sending responses in response to a DEBUG request.

I have disabled debugging in the web config file using the  tag.

I see that there are several machine.config and machine.config.default files on the server, and I have set retail="true" for the deployment tag in all of them, and the configuration editor in EES shows the retail attribute as true.

Still, when I point curl --trace - at my site, I still get trace information.

What else do I need to do?

Comment: Show the trace information you see from the `curl --trace`

Answer (score 0):

Lets look at the `curl --trace` information you receive. The important thing is what ISAPI modules and handler are processing and handling the requests `curl --trace` sends.

Show the trace log.

Only standard Microsoft ISAPI modules and handlers have to obey the ASP.NET *.config parameters. If you are using some third-party modules on your server than you will have to look into their configuration.

Comment: I sent the curl command from a MAC term session.  From what I read in the man page, it is independent of PHP.

"curl is a tool to transfer data from or to a server, using one of the supported protocols (DICT, FILE, FTP, FTPS, GOPHER, HTTP, HTTPS, IMAP, IMAPS, LDAP, LDAPS, POP3, POP3S, RTMP, RTSP, SCP, SFTP, SMB, SMBS, SMTP, SMTPS, TELNET and TFTP). The command is designed to work without user interaction."

Comment: @gary_z what http module is handling curl requests at your iis app?

Comment: Cool: I do see lots of references to curl in association with PHP, but I am using it simply to elicit a response to a HTTP request.

Answer (score 0):

Putting the appropriate tags in machine.config and web.config resolved the problem.  It seems that our security is testing something different than what curl tests.